# Ajax.Beginform - send only the values from checkboxes that are checked?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have a form that has a textbox (called name) and a set of checkboxes and a set of radios. I want to send the value of the textbox, an array containing only the value of the checkboxes that are checked and the value of the radio checked. I know that I could use the jquery ajax syntax for this, but I want to do it with Ajax.BeginForm. From what I can tell the Ajax option OnBegin might be the key to this, but I cannot figure out how to alter the request before it goes to the action.

****EDIT:****

I've reworked the code based on Stephen's answer, but I am still running into problems with just getting it to render properly. Here's the code:

```
public class RecipeSearch
{
    public List<Recipe> Recipe { get; set; }
    public List<Meal> MealSettings { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> MainIngredient { get; set; }
}

public class Meal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

}

    public ActionResult Search()
    {

        RecipeSearch recipe = new RecipeSearch();
        recipe = recipeSearchDetails(null, null);

        recipe.Recipe = dbContext.Recipes
            .OrderBy(r => r.name)
            .Where(r => r.name.Contains("") || string.IsNullOrEmpty(""))
            .ToList();

        RecipeSearch recipe = new RecipeSearch();
        recipe.MealSettings = new List<Meal>();
        var meals = dbContext.MealCategories
                    .OrderBy(r => r.name)
                    .ToList();

        var MainIngredient = dbContext.Maincategories
                    .OrderBy(r => r.name).ToList();

        foreach (var item in meals)
        {
            recipe.MealSettings.Add(new Meal { DisplayName = item.name, Value = true, Id = item.mealCategoryId });
        }



        recipe.Recipe = dbContext.Recipes
                        .OrderByDescending(r => r.MealCategory.name)
                        .Where(mc => mc.MealCategory.name == mealCategory || (mealCategory == null))
                        .Where(m => m.Ingredients.FirstOrDefault().SubCategory.name == mainIngredient || (mainIngredient == null)).ToList();

        return PartialView("_search", recipe);
    }
```

**Model:**

```
@model RecipeTrackerMVC.Models.Search.RecipeSearch


@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MealSettings.Count(); i++)
   {
      <li>
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.MealSettings[i].Value)
           @Html.LabelFor(r => Model.MealSettings[i].Value, Model.MealSettings[i].DisplayName)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(r => Model.MealSettings[i].Id)
      </li>
   }
```

The browser is rendering the following for each meal:
[image]

Is the name supposed to render so sloppy?

In addition to that, I made an AJAX call and this is the data that I get. All items were unchecked except for id 12 - but for some reason that one has two values and I'm not sure why. Also, I thought with this style (checkboxfor) only items that were checked were supposed to be sent in the request?

```
name:s
allCategories:false
MealSettings[0].Value:false
MealSettings[0].Id:7
MealSettings[1].Value:false
MealSettings[1].Id:8
MealSettings[2].Value:false
MealSettings[2].Id:9
MealSettings[3].Value:false
MealSettings[3].Id:1
MealSettings[4].Value:false
MealSettings[4].Id:10
MealSettings[5].Value:false
MealSettings[5].Id:11
MealSettings[6].Value:false
MealSettings[6].Id:12
MealSettings[7].Value:true
MealSettings[7].Value:false
MealSettings[7].Id:4
MealSettings[8].Value:false
MealSettings[8].Id:3
MealSettings[9].Value:false
MealSettings[9].Id:17
MealSettings[10].Value:false
MealSettings[10].Id:2
allIngredients:all
allIngredients:false
startTime:
endTime:
prepTime:0
cookTime:0
standTime:0
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

And when I make my Ajax call with this syntax, the model shows as null:

```
    public ActionResult Search(IEnumerable<RecipeSearch> model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `MealCategory` is a list of boolean values, using `@Html.CheckBoxFor` will generate the html for post back (similar for radio buttons)

```
@model yourModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  ....
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MealCategory.Count; i++) {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i])
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i])
  }
  ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

**Edit:** Further to comments
I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I suggest creating a view model to represent possible selections, and create action methods in your controller to select the options as follows:

```
public class MealSelection
{
  public int ID { get; set;} // to generate a hidden input for postback
  public bool IsSelected { get; set;} // to generate a checkbox
  public string Name { get; set;} // for display in the view
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Selections()
{  
  List<MealSelection> selections = new ..// Generate a list selections
  return View(selections)
}

[HtpPost]
public ActionResult Selections(IEnumerable<MealSelection> model)
{
  IEnumerable<MealSelection> selections = model.Where(m => m.IsSelected);
  // foreach MealSelection in selections, get the ID and do something with it
  return RedirectToAction(..to some view that displays the selections..);
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<MealSelection>
```

then loop (modify above) to create hidden input for the `ID`, checkbox for `IsSelected` and label for `Name`.

Comment: Meal Category is not a list of boolean values. I'll update my original question with the model now.

Comment: @Yecats, So what is the boolean value that you are creating a checkbox for?

Comment: I might be a bit confused. :/ These checkboxes are for filtering. It's querying the DB for a list of the types that the user can pick and then if they choose to select that one I want to pass the ID to the action so I can use it to filter the result set in the DB.

Comment: @Yecats, I've edited my answer to suggest how you might be able to accomplish this (although I'm a little unsure of exactly what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I've been able to do all (except for the Post, which I'm working on now.) I've ran into a few problems and updated my original post accordingly.

Comment: @Yecats, What do you mean by "Is the name supposed to render so sloppy?" With regard to the form values, yes its correct. Notice how the @ChekBoxFor() method renders 2 elements, an `input type='checkbox'` and an `input type='hidden' value='false'`. This is necessary because unchecked checkboxes do not post back (the hidden input is necessary to post back a default value for binding). When the model binder reads the values it ignores any subsequent values with the same name, so for item 12, it reads `true` and ignores the following `false` value

Comment: Regarding the name - I wasn't expecting it to show as MealSettings[#].Value, and I wasn't sure if I had done something wrong. In that case, it appears my only problem is my original issue - When I added the model parameter it was null upon the ajax call. (See the bottom of my post for the snippet of code.) Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54404/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-yecats).